# How do I make an Excel chart which has differing area colours?

Tags: excel

Basically, I want to make something which looks like this:

[image: Example]

I have no idea where to even start on this question. I've checked the line graphs and the area graphs on my Excel 2015 for Mac, but I can't find anything which would be anything like this.

My data is organised in three columns like so:

```
Date | Debt | President
=======================
1987 | $$$  | Reagan
1988 | $$$  | Reagan
1989 | $$$  | Bush
1990 | $$$  | Bush
1991 | $$$  | Bush
1992 | $$$  | Bush
1993 | $$$  | Clinton
1994 | $$$  | Clinton
```

Comment: Set up two charts, one red the other purple, and in the red chart  make the values =0 where you want the purple to 'show through' as it were, and on the purple chart make the values =0 where you want the red chart to 'show through. So, each chart is transparent where you want to see the other chart. will post more detail when it comes to mind, but, from memory, you use a bar chart and make the overlap 100%, instead of having them side by side. The data series ranges are where you put =IF formulae to include things in or out. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. And it only took five hours on and off of exasperated problem solving! I've always hated how people who solve their own problems never post the solution on the internet (like [this](http://xkcd.com/979/)). So, I posted the solution here. Hope it isn't too far out of decorum.

To accomplish this obnoxiously annoying feat, I created three new columns

```
Date | Debt | Reagan | Bush | Clinton | President
=================================================
1987 | $$$  | $$$    | #N/A | #N/A    | Reagan
1988 | $$$  | $$$    | #N/A | #N/A    | Reagan
1989 | $$$  | #N/A   | $$$  | #N/A    | Bush
1990 | $$$  | #N/A   | $$$  | #N/A    | Bush
1991 | $$$  | #N/A   | $$$  | #N/A    | Bush
1992 | $$$  | #N/A   | $$$  | #N/A    | Bush
1993 | $$$  | #N/A   | #N/A | $$$     | Clinton
1994 | $$$  | #N/A   | #N/A | $$$     | Clinton
```

I was able to generate that pattern by using an if statement for the `C`, `D`, and `E` columns: `IF(C2="Reagan",B2, NA())`, with changed `C2` and `"Reagan"` values where relevant (that is, for the Bush column, `D2` and `"Bush"`, and so on).

This created a series of lines. I plotted those lines using the Excel plot function. Then, I right-clicked to have those lines and told them to plot as areas. Then, I had what I wanted.